# Average calculations on columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, reshape

I need to calculate the most recent values, that is last few rows of each group and then average on the particular columns

```
Input data: 
Date        Prod    Bucket  Bal
31/01/2013  a01     1001    10
31/01/2013  a01     1002    20
31/01/2013  a01     1003    10
31/01/2013  a01     1004    24
31/01/2013  a01     1005    20
28/02/2013  a01     1001    20
28/02/2013  a01     1002    15
28/02/2013  a01     1003    25
28/02/2013  a01     1004    20
28/02/2013  a01     1005    50
31/03/2013  a01     1001    30
31/03/2013  a01     1002    10
31/03/2013  a01     1003    20
31/03/2013  a01     1004    10
31/03/2013  a01     1005    25
30/04/2013  a01     1001    20
30/04/2013  a01     1002    20
30/04/2013  a01     1003    15
30/04/2013  a01     1004    25
30/04/2013  a01     1005    10
31/01/2014  a02     1001    30
31/01/2014  a02     1002    10
31/01/2014  a02     1003    20
31/01/2014  a02     1004    10
31/01/2014  a02     1005    20
28/02/2014  a02     1001    20
28/02/2014  a02     1002    15
28/02/2014  a02     1003    25
28/02/2014  a02     1004    10
28/02/2014  a02     1005    20
31/03/2014  a02     1001    15
31/03/2014  a02     1002    25
31/03/2014  a02     1003    20
31/03/2014  a02     1004    50
31/03/2014  a02     1005    20
30/04/2014  a02     1001    10
30/04/2014  a02     1002    20
30/04/2014  a02     1003    20
30/04/2014  a02     1004    15
30/04/2014  a02     1005    20
```

expected output:

```
Date        Prod    Bucket  Bal Most_recent 3_month_avg 6_month_avg 12_month_avg    12 month Max Avg. 
31/01/2013  a01     1001    10                  
31/01/2013  a01     1002    20                  
31/01/2013  a01     1003    10                  
31/01/2013  a01     1004    24                  
31/01/2013  a01     1005    20                  
28/02/2013  a01     1001    20                  
28/02/2013  a01     1002    15                  
28/02/2013  a01     1003    25                  
28/02/2013  a01     1004    20                  
28/02/2013  a01     1005    50                  
31/03/2013  a01     1001    30                  
31/03/2013  a01     1002    10                  
31/03/2013  a01     1003    20                  
31/03/2013  a01     1004    10                  
31/03/2013  a01     1005    25                  
30/04/2013  a01     1001    20  20              
30/04/2013  a01     1002    20  20              
30/04/2013  a01     1003    15  15              
30/04/2013  a01     1004    25  25              
30/04/2013  a01     1005    10  10              
31/01/2014  a02     1001    30                  
31/01/2014  a02     1002    10                  
31/01/2014  a02     1003    20                  
31/01/2014  a02     1004    10                  
31/01/2014  a02     1005    20                  
28/02/2014  a02     1001    20                  
28/02/2014  a02     1002    15                  
28/02/2014  a02     1003    25                  
28/02/2014  a02     1004    10                  
28/02/2014  a02     1005    20                  
31/03/2014  a02     1001    15                  
31/03/2014  a02     1002    25                  
31/03/2014  a02     1003    20                  
31/03/2014  a02     1004    50                  
31/03/2014  a02     1005    20                  
30/04/2014  a02     1001    10  10              
30/04/2014  a02     1002    20  20              
30/04/2014  a02     1003    20  20              
30/04/2014  a02     1004    15  15              
30/04/2014  a02     1005    20  20
```

Code used for most recent:

```
Most_recent <- DF[,ncol(DF)]
MR <- cbind(Most_recent)
```

but  this will only print if there is one group of data, but in this data, there are 2 groups a01 and a02 and will be more ... a03, a04 and so on.

Similary need to calculate avg of Bal.

Need to use only, data.table, reshape, zoo and gtools - only these 4 libraries.

Please help, thanks in Advance.

Comment: @OrhanYazar Expected output is already mentioned.

Comment: You speak about average...where is the average?

Comment: @Sotos calculate avg for Bal for each group.

Comment: Something like `setDT(DT)[, mean(Bal[as.IDate(Date, "%d/%m/%Y") == max(as.IDate(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"))]), by = Prod]`? (setting performance aside) or I don't get it? Or `DT[, mean(Bal[Date == last(Date)]), by = Prod]` (if data set is ordered). Also, what is the role of the `Bucket` column here? Is it supposed to be taken into consideration?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am fine printing the Avg's. My main issue is gettitng the most recent values. Please help me in getting them print as expected in the output. Most recent is the last values of each group.

Comment: Why do you need to print values? Also, doesn't `DT[, Bal[Date == last(Date)], by = Prod]` already prints them?

Comment: I am not very fluent with `data.table` but this `setDT(df)[, avg := mean(Bal), by = .(Prod, rleid(Date))][, avg := tail(avg, 1), by = Prod][]` will create an `avg` column with the average of only the most recent days

Comment: @Sotos How about just `DT[, mean(Bal[Date == last(Date)]), by = Prod]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oh `data.table` has `last` too? neat. I guess It's up to the OP to get it in the format they want

Comment: @Sotos `last` is pretty redundant function IMO, one could just do `Date[.N]` instead.

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes. I was trying to do it with `.SD[.N]` but couldn't get it

Comment: Or `DT[DT[, .(Date = max(Date)), by = Prod], on = .(Prod, Date), most_recent := Bal][]` for adding only the most recent `Bal`-values to a new column.

Comment: @Jaap i am getting the below error: - - 

data$bal[data$bal[, .(DATE = max(DATE)), by = Prod], on = .(Prod, DATE), most_recent := data$bal][]


Error: could not find function "."

Comment: You need to load the package and convert to a data.ble first: `library(data.table); setDT(DT)`. Furthermore, when working with a data.table you don't need to specify the `data$` part.

Comment: @Jaap - still the same error. Is this something related to R version. Coz we i have R version 3.1.1 and cannot upgrade the server on any conditions.

Comment: Which version of data.table do you have?

Comment: @Jaap data.table - 1.9.6